# How does SocialDaily.com gets detailed datas of a Facebook page?

Tags: facebook

It is possible to get detailed information about a page I type in. How is it possible? How do they get real time info from Facebook?

Answer (score 0):

They're just doing daily scheduled queries I guess... You can get the public page stats like this if you know the page_id:

```
GET /{page_id}?fields=id,name,likes,new_like_count,checkins,talking_about_count
```

If you don't know the page_id, but the URL on Facebook, use the following FQL query to get it:

```
select id from object_url where url="{FULL_PAGE_URL}"
```

You can also pull the stats in one call from a given URL:

```
select page_id, name, fan_count, checkins, talking_about_count from page where page_id in (select id from object_url where url="{FULL_PAGE_URL}")
```

See

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/page/
- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/object_url/